# Net Use. Add user if user name is of two words

Tags: cmd.exe

I want to add sharedrive using net use and cmd but I can't do this. Username is Rafał Roznowski (polish username). It works only on One word. How I can do this?

```
net use s: \\192.168.1.65\bazy\zasoby /user:"Rafał Roznowski" password
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the full username.
Use the userid of the user.
The userid NEVER contains spaces.

Comment: And how to get 'userid' ? Cmd - whoami - "no id".

Comment: echo %username%

Comment: `net user` or `WMIC useraccount get FullName, Name`.

Comment: echo %username% -> Rafał Roznowski

Comment: @Mantykora7 Is it a userid that exists on the other (192.168.1.65) computer? In that case run whoami on that computer. You own computer will have no knowledge of the "foreign" user-account.

Answer (score 1):

This modification worked for me:

```
net use s: \\192.168.1.65\bazy\zasoby password "/user:Rafał Roznowski"
```

You will notice that in addition to moving the left quotation mark, I also moved the `password` parameter to before the `/user` parameter to comply with the `net use` command syntax.  One other consideration is that in my network, I needed to specify the domain of the specified user, which would change your command as follows:

```
net use s: \\192.168.1.65\bazy\zasoby password "/user:domainname\Rafał Roznowski"
```

In general, though, using spaces in usernames, although permitted, is not a good practice for maximizing compatibility.

Alternatively, you may be able to map the drive via the Windows File Explorer GUI.  In this case, you would overcome the space in the username by placing it entirely in quotes as `"Rafał Roznowski"` or `"domainname\Rafał Roznowski"`, pictured here:

[Windows Map Network Drive Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XYuo.jpg)
[image: Windows Map Network Drive Screenshot]